# How to get Google CSE RESTFull API Result's Next Page & confusion on daily request limit?

Tags: google-custom-search

I am using Google CSE Restlful API. And my code to get results is

```
 Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CseResource.ListRequest listRequest = svc.Cse.List(query);
        listRequest.Cx = cx;
        Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data.Search search = listRequest.Fetch();
 foreach (Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.Data.Result result in search.Items)
        {
          //do something with items
        }
```

It returns me 10 results out of total 100 . To see results of next 10 records I have to

```
 listRequest.Start = 11;
 search = listRequest.Fetch();
```

And now I my 'search.Items' have results from 11-20 . 
Now I have 2 questions:

1- Is it right way to get the results of next page ( next 10 records) ?

2- And doing so would it mean that I have consumed 2 request out of 100 allowed requests per day ?

If this is correct then effectively user can only get total of 1000 results per day from Google CSE API.

So it means if I have to see all 100 results of my first query I would have to make 10 requests.

Thanks,
Wasim

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's the right way: setting the start parameter to the next index will request the next paginated results from your query.

You are right also on the second question, each request (paginated or non paginated) is counted between the max of 100 allowed per day, resulting of a total of 1000 max results per day.